# deleting an element on stack in C

Tags: c, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here I made a simple test to check if an element on stack can be deleted .

```
// This program test whether an object is dynamically allocated and passed as a parameter to a function , \
//free()ed in that function , then would it really get free()ed or still existing

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data ;
    struct node *next;
} node ;

void deleteElement(int *p)
{

    free(p);
}

void deleteNode(node *node)
{
    free(node);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10 ;
    int *p = &i ;

    node *parent = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    parent->data = 10;

    node *child = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    parent->next = child ;

    deleteElement(p);
    printf("\np : %d",*p);

    deleteNode(parent);
    printf("\nparent node: %d",parent->data);
    printf("\nchild node : %d",child->data);
    return 0 ;
}
```

But I get the following error

```
codejack@ubuntu:~/Code::Blocks/ProgrammingTests$ ./a.out 
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff9e9fa284 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7f34da65cb96]
./a.out[0x4005c4]
./a.out[0x400635]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f34da5ff76d]
./a.out[0x4004c9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 383254                             /home/codejack/Code::Blocks/ProgrammingTests/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 07:00 383254                             /home/codejack/Code::Blocks/ProgrammingTests/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 07:00 383254                             /home/codejack/Code::Blocks/ProgrammingTests/a.out
0190a000-0192b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f34da3c8000-7f34da3dd000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 197806                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34da3dd000-7f34da5dc000 ---p 00015000 07:00 197806                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34da5dc000-7f34da5dd000 r--p 00014000 07:00 197806                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34da5dd000-7f34da5de000 rw-p 00015000 07:00 197806                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34da5de000-7f34da793000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 700468                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f34da793000-7f34da992000 ---p 001b5000 07:00 700468                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f34da992000-7f34da996000 r--p 001b4000 07:00 700468                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f34da996000-7f34da998000 rw-p 001b8000 07:00 700468                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f34da998000-7f34da99d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34da99d000-7f34da9bf000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 700456                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f34daba5000-7f34daba8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34dabbc000-7f34dabbf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34dabbf000-7f34dabc0000 r--p 00022000 07:00 700456                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f34dabc0000-7f34dabc2000 rw-p 00023000 07:00 700456                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fff9e9db000-7fff9e9fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff9e9ff000-7fff9ea00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Actually I was stuck  while implementing the deletion of a tree . I deleted the leaf nodes using `free()` and now the parent would become leaf nodes , and delete those nodes too using recursion .
But the problem is leaf node is not getting deleted actually , its still there .
And also the method i followed in deletion of tree is as follows

```
void deleteTree(struct node *root)
{
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
       free(root);
    }
    else
    {
       if(root->left != NULL)
            deleteTree(root->left);
       if(root->right != NULL)
            deleteTree(root->right);
    }
}
```

This method deleted only the leaf nodes , and the corresponding parent nodes were not deleted  . After debugging in XCode I found out that the leaf nodes were not deleted , They were still there.
**So why this method dint show any error as the test i done ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three obvious errors:

(1) `deleteElement(p)` ends up calling `free()` on a pointer that was not allocated with `malloc()`.

(2) This code:

```
deleteNode(parent);
printf("\nparent node: %d",parent->data);
```

references the variable `parent` after it has been deleted.

(3) In `deleteTree()`, after freeing child nodes, you retain a reference to them, so that you'll never delete non-leaf nodes.

Comment: Sir,(2) prints 0 as output , (3) why the reference still exists ??

Comment: (2) Might print anything. It's totally undefined. In fact, the most likely contents of deleted memory is whatever was put there, so code will often behave correctly despite being wrong. It's not my job to explain what it does--it's wrong, and it's allowed to do anything.

(3) The `left` and `right` pointers are never cleared.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `free()` pointer which is not allocated memory. In your case, you are trying to free memory of stack which is in valid.

```
void deleteElement(int *p)
{

    free(p);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10 ;
    int *p = &i ;
    ....
    deleteElement(p);
    ...
}
```

---

In `deleteTree()` method you should reset the `->left` or `->right` appropriately after its `free()`ed, otherwise it will try to access invalid/freed memory.

```
void deleteTree(struct node *root)
{
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
       free(root);
    }
    else
    {
       if(root->left != NULL)
       {
            deleteTree(root->left);
            root->left = NULL;
       }
       if(root->right != NULL)
       {
            deleteTree(root->right);
            root->right = NULL;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean when a pointer is passed as a pointer , and when it is on stack ,then  it has not been allocated any memory ?

Comment: In the deleteTree() , why did it worked ?? why the big error is not shown in that case ?

Comment: @CodeJack, yes you should not free pointer to which you have not allocated memory explicitly.